# Why is my Texture Quad positioned incorrectly with glTexCoord2f using LWJGL?

Tags: opengl, 2d, lwjgl

I am going to make a adventure game in 2D with Grass,Trees and other things if i can make these. My problem is that when i use glTexCoord2f to clamp the texture to a quad then they get seperated from each others about 25 pixels. These quads is supposed to be connected together like any 2D games.

Im loading them with SlickUtil and the size of the Texture is 100x100

Here's my source code for rendering quads and InitGL

```
public static void Render(){
    example--;
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    Color.white.bind();
    system.Game.ground.bind();
    GL11.glTranslatef(example, 0, 0);
    //I used for loop for cloning quad at each side.
    for(int x = 0; x <= width; x++){
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x * 100, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x * 100 + 100, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x * 100 + 100, 100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x * 100, 100);
        GL11.glEnd();
    }
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Heres my InitGL Code.

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);              
GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);         

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

GL11.glViewport(0,0,width,height);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: you can start by not using the fixed function pipeline but instead use shaders and VBOs

Comment: What's the size of your textures? How are you loading them? This sounds like it could be a common problem where you're using a library that rounds up texture sizes to powers of 2, while your actual texture sizes are not powers of 2.

Comment: Looks like you tried to include a screenshot in your question but something got messed up... can you do something about `![][1]` in your question? If you link to the screenshot, I can embed it for you.

Comment: The problem was i didn't have enough reputations to include the image.

Answer (score 0):

SlickUtil only reads Textures with dimensions that are powers of two. The reason is, that only since OpenGL 2.0, OpenGL could read textures with non-power-of-two dimensions. Try loading a texture with the dimensions of 128 by 128 pixels. Then display it with 100 by 100 pixels (like you did in your example).